# Is there a more idiomatic way for this pattern in Rust?

Tags: rust, polymorphism

I am writing a code generator in Rust which can produce output in different programming languages. By a command line argument the user can choose the produced language. I am using a trait `Outputter` to define all the methods that the outputters must implement. Does my solution make sense? Is there a more idiomatic way in Rust to do this? Thanks for any suggestions!

Here is my simplified code:

```
use std::io::{Write, self};

struct Input {
    values: Vec<i32>,
}

trait Outputter<T: Write> {
    fn file_header(&self, _input: &Input, _buffer: &mut T) -> Result<(), String> {
        Ok(())
    }
    fn file_footer(&self, _input: &Input, _buffer: &mut T) -> Result<(), String> {
        Ok(())
    }

}

struct Javascript {}
impl<T> Outputter<T> for Javascript where T: Write {}

struct Rust {}

impl<T> Outputter<T> for Rust where T: Write {
    fn file_header(&self, input: &Input, buffer: &mut T) -> Result<(), String> {
        writeln!(buffer, "// header of rust file!").unwrap();
        writeln!(buffer, "{:?}", input.values).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }

    fn file_footer(&self, _input: &Input, buffer: &mut T) -> Result<(), String> {
        writeln!(buffer, "// footer of rust file!").unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct Cpp {}

impl<T> Outputter<T> for Cpp where T: Write {
    fn file_header(&self, input: &Input, buffer: &mut T) -> Result<(), String> {
        writeln!(buffer, "// header of c++ file!").unwrap();
        writeln!(buffer, "{:?}", input.values).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
}

enum Format {
    Rust,
    Cpp,
    Javascript
}

struct Generator {
}

impl Generator
{
    fn generate<T: Write>(input: &Input, format: Format, buffer: &mut T) -> Result<(), String> {
        let outputter: Box<dyn Outputter<T>> = match format {
            Format::Rust => Box::new(Rust {}),
            Format::Cpp => Box::new(Cpp {}),
            Format::Javascript => Box::new(Javascript {}),
        };

        outputter.file_header(input, buffer)?;
        outputter.file_footer(input, buffer)?;

        Ok(())
    } 
}


fn main() {
    let input = Input { values: vec![1,2,3,4,5] };

    // like this we could also pass a file instead
    let mut buffer = Box::new(io::stdout());

    // choose a formatter at runtime by command line argument
    Generator::generate(&input, Format::Rust, &mut buffer).unwrap();
    Generator::generate(&input, Format::Cpp, &mut buffer).unwrap();
    Generator::generate(&input, Format::Javascript, &mut buffer).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: "Is there a more idiomatic way in Rust to do this?" To do what? Write a multi-language code generator? I feel like that stretches the definition of a programming idiom past its breaking point. It sounds like maybe you're more interested in a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust).

Comment: One thing you could do to be more idiomatic is to make `_buffer` argument be `T` since there is an [impl<T: Write> Write for &mut T](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-for-%26mut+W)

Comment: Thank you @AleksanderKrauze for this hint. But I am not fluent enough in Rust yet to understand it. I tried to change `_buffer: &mut T` to `_buffer: T` but then I get a lot of complaints, that the value is moved and not mutable.

Comment: This implementation means that if you have a `T` that is `Write` and have a function that accepts `Write` argument you can pass to it `&mut T` (thus not transferring an ownership). So in `Generator::generate` when you are calling `file_header` and `file_footer` you can pass `&mut buff` instead of `buff`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Box<dyn Outputter>` is absolutely necessary.
All is driven by the variants of `Format`: each of them is considered in order to instantiate the corresponding `Box<dyn Outputter>`.

I would directly implement `Outputter` on this format information (`StaticFormat` in the following example); once this choice is made, everything follows without the need of dynamic allocation and dynamic dispatch.

I tried to minimize the changes in your example.
It would probably be beneficial to add some helper functions in order minimise some typing.

The [`enum_dispatch`](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/) crate can help avoid the explicit forwarding of the trait functions (since this forwarding is systematic).

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

struct Input {
    values: Vec<i32>,
}

trait Outputter<T: Write> {
    fn file_header(
        &self,
        _input: &Input,
        _buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        Ok(())
    }
    fn file_footer(
        &self,
        _input: &Input,
        _buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct Javascript {}
impl<T> Outputter<T> for Javascript where T: Write {}

struct Rust {}

impl<T> Outputter<T> for Rust
where
    T: Write,
{
    fn file_header(
        &self,
        input: &Input,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        writeln!(buffer, "// header of rust file!").unwrap();
        writeln!(buffer, "{:?}", input.values).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }

    fn file_footer(
        &self,
        _input: &Input,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        writeln!(buffer, "// footer of rust file!").unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct Cpp {}

impl<T> Outputter<T> for Cpp
where
    T: Write,
{
    fn file_header(
        &self,
        input: &Input,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        writeln!(buffer, "// header of c++ file!").unwrap();
        writeln!(buffer, "{:?}", input.values).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
}

enum Format {
    Rust,
    Cpp,
    Javascript,
}

struct Generator {}

impl Generator {
    fn generate<T: Write>(
        input: &Input,
        format: Format,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        let outputter: Box<dyn Outputter<T>> = match format {
            Format::Rust => Box::new(Rust {}),
            Format::Cpp => Box::new(Cpp {}),
            Format::Javascript => Box::new(Javascript {}),
        };
        outputter.file_header(input, buffer)?;
        outputter.file_footer(input, buffer)?;
        Ok(())
    }

    //******** Changed from here...

    fn static_generate<T: Write>(
        input: &Input,
        format: StaticFormat,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        format.file_header(input, buffer)?;
        format.file_footer(input, buffer)?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

enum StaticFormat {
    Rust(Rust),
    Cpp(Cpp),
    Javascript(Javascript),
}

impl<T> Outputter<T> for StaticFormat
where
    T: Write,
{
    fn file_header(
        &self,
        input: &Input,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        match self {
            Self::Rust(o) => o.file_header(input, buffer),
            Self::Cpp(o) => o.file_header(input, buffer),
            Self::Javascript(o) => o.file_header(input, buffer),
        }
    }

    fn file_footer(
        &self,
        input: &Input,
        buffer: &mut T,
    ) -> Result<(), String> {
        match self {
            Self::Rust(o) => o.file_footer(input, buffer),
            Self::Cpp(o) => o.file_footer(input, buffer),
            Self::Javascript(o) => o.file_footer(input, buffer),
        }
    }
}

//******** ... to here

fn main() {
    let input = Input {
        values: vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    };

    // like this we could also pass a file instead
    let mut buffer = Box::new(io::stdout());

    // choose a formatter at runtime by command line argument
    Generator::generate(&input, Format::Rust, &mut buffer).unwrap();
    Generator::generate(&input, Format::Cpp, &mut buffer).unwrap();
    Generator::generate(&input, Format::Javascript, &mut buffer).unwrap();

    println!("~~~~~~~~");

    Generator::static_generate(
        &input,
        StaticFormat::Rust(Rust {}),
        &mut buffer,
    )
    .unwrap();
    Generator::static_generate(
        &input,
        StaticFormat::Cpp(Cpp {}),
        &mut buffer,
    )
    .unwrap();
    Generator::static_generate(
        &input,
        StaticFormat::Javascript(Javascript {}),
        &mut buffer,
    )
    .unwrap();
}
/*
// header of rust file!
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// footer of rust file!
// header of c++ file!
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
~~~~~~~~
// header of rust file!
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// footer of rust file!
// header of c++ file!
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I now also learned the correct programming terms for my questions like 'dynamic dispatch' and 'traited objects'.